# Why doesn't spring inject secrets from vault?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-cloud, minikube, hashicorp-vault

I run my `spring` application in `minikube`, here is the jdbc part of my config file:

```
spring:
  profiles.active: prod
  main.allow-circular-references: true
  datasource:
    url: ${spring_datasource_url}
    username: ${spring_datasource_username}
    password: ${spring_datasource_password}
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    sql-script-encoding: UTF-8
```

I try to get my secrets from vault when the app is starting:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    vault:
      enabled: true
      fail-fast: true
      config.lifecycle.enabled: false
      scheme: http
      host: ${VAULT_HOST}
      port: ${VAULT_PORT}
      authentication: TOKEN
      token: ${VAULT_TOKEN}
      kv:
        enabled: true
        backend: backend
        application-name: ${spring.application.name}
        profiles: ${spring.profiles.active}
  config:import: vault://
```

and I have such `kv` strore in my vault, and I do have a key named `spring_datasource_url`. My kv path in vault is `vault/secrets/backend/show/words/prod`, `words` is my application-name, `prod` is my active profile.

But after starting my app, I'm getting this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.postgresql.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${spring_datasource_url}
```

Seems like the app cannot parse the key from vault. What is my mistake of solving it?

Comment: can you share access to your project repository?

Answer (score 0):

I was blind. All I needed was to change `config:import` to `config.import`